# Can someone convert this code

Tags: python

Hey I have some code in C but at the same time I need that bit of code in python,
is there a way i can convert `for(i = 0; i < MAXFDS; i++)` to python i'v tried `for i in range(i = 0, MAXFDS = i++)` but that will not work please help.

Comment: Nopes, SO is no code conversion site.

Comment: ^ i was hoping someone who knew more about python then me could help not use a site lol, sites are over rated and not accurate

Comment: Please read [Ask] page first. Also, try to re-word your question.

Comment: Why not read the python.org docs? Here is a good start: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?
`for i in range(0, MAXDFS)`

Comment: This worked thanks but instead of for (i in range(0, MAXDFS)) i did for (i in range(0, MAXDFS)

Comment: Yea, edited... `(` is kinda muscle memory after a `for` :P. Please consider accepting an answer if it helped.

Comment: I'm going to make this the right answer in a bit it says i need to wait 10 mins :)

Answer (score -1):

I would do :

```
for i in xrange(MAXFDS):
    pass
```

Edit:

for python 3

```
for i in range(MAXFDS):
    pass
```

Comment: That's my point.  It works only in Python 2, not in Python 3.